# After 16.04 upgrade install systemd-sysv failed, how can I check that I fixed it?

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, systemd

I updated to 16.04LTS from 15.10. It has been reported as a bug that the message
 '**not installed systemd-sysv**' appears, which it also did on my machine and the installation aborted with the suggestion that I ran **apt-get -f install**, which I did.

Now there are no errors on startup but I would like to know how to determine if the systemd-sysv has been installed correctly

The bug report I mentioned is at [systemd-sysv install bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1569099)